# git: should I initialize a git repository on the root of a project or one in each important section of the project?

Tags: git

As mentioned in the question, I have a root dir for the project, within which are housed four sub-dirs each containing scripts/binaries and dotfiles related to a specific, separate aspect of the project. Should I initialize a git repository

1. On the project root
2. One in each sub-dir
3. Both (i.e., one in the project root and one in each directory)

I currently have one initialized on the project root. When I run `git status` there, it only shows me the sub-directories which have had modifications, not the actual files which changed within them. So with this setup, I was wondering whether I should run `git add <subdirectory>` or `git add <path/to/file>`... And thus began my confusion.

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the repository layout, all of the options you have listed are possible! The simplest option is to just create one git repository in the project root. I would recommend you use this option unless your project is very complex.

Creating one in each subdirectory can have its advantages when changes in the directories are independent, but it will complicate working with the repositories.

Creating one in each subdirectory *and* the project root is what you'd do to make use of [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). By making all directories git submodules, you can use them as independent repositories and commit changes separately, while the root git repository can be used to track which versions of the specific submodules go together.

Regarding the output of `git status`: If a directory is entirely new, `git status` will indeed only show that directory - for brevity so that the output doesn't get too long. Actually **git does not care about directories by themselves** (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590753/why-doesnt-git-version-directories)), only about the files in them. If you have an empty directory, it doesn't matter to git, and you cannot commit an empty directory.

Git will only store files with their full paths, such as `directory/subdirectory/file`, while it won't store information about the directories. (this is why a common practice for almost-empty directories has developed: creating an empty file called `.gitkeep` to keep the directory around without any other directory entries)

As such, it doesn't maky any difference if you `git add` an entire directory or all the files in it. Adding the directory is just the shorthand way to tell git to add all files under that.